# How to encrypt and verify password in asp.net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, password-encryption, password-hash

I used following tutorial to hash passwords to my db. I would like to ask to more experienced developers here if this method is still "up to date"? I wouldn't like to have security problems.

Here is the link in question: [How to encrypt and decrypt password in asp.net using C#?](https://chandradev819.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-password-in-asp-net-using-c/). I modified a little bit the code so that it would always use SHA512 as hash algorithm. I also never specify a salt but let it generate it (second parameter = null).

Thanks in advance for your help, wish you all a nice week!

Greetings

Comment: You never want the ability to "decrypt" passwords.  Passwords are _hashed_ (and salted) which is a **one way** function.

Comment: Short answer: you don't. Long answer: you hash the password (you can't _decrypt_ a hash). The same data going into a hash algorithm produces the same result, so that's how you verify the password.

Comment: The title of the tutorial is maybe not perfect, but if you take a look to it you will see that it's a method to verify a correct password, not to decrypt it. Edit: I updated the title ;)

Comment: Please ask a self-contained question. It's hard to maintain quality with offsite links. Any answer here would basically be a comment on a website. If that site goes down or gets modified, the answers become obsolete or even misleading.

Comment: Your question as to whether it is "up to date" is probably better suited to [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and seems to have a decent answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

Comment: Acutally no - this is common knowledge. Generally salted passwords are still "the way" (and likely are forever - pure simple logic, though hash algos and number of iterations may change)

Comment: encryption != hashing. With passwords, you hash them, because you don't want them to be decryptable.

Comment: @John "Short answer: you don't" Unless requirements dictate you must. There are definitely occasions where you MUST be able to retrieve encrypted data. Which, sometimes, includes passwords.

Answer (score 4):

As I'm asp.net beginner to answer it,I used following code that might help you where you can encrypt the password and save to db and when retrieve that encrypted string from db then decrypt to match your verifying password.Following code are tested for your (pwd) cryptogrphy.

**Design File**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text="Arslan Ali" runat="server" placeHolder="Enter Password"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Encrypt" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Decrypt" OnClick="Button2_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
</div>
</form>
```

**In your Code File Required NameSpaces**

```
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

**Define Hash String**

```
    string hash = @"foxle@rn";
```

**Encrypt**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text);
    using(MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5=new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() {Key=keys,Mode=CipherMode.ECB,Padding=PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
        {
            ICryptoTransform transform=tripleDes.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] results=transform.TransformFinalBlock(data,0,data.Length);
            Label1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(results);
        }
    }
}
```

**Decrypt**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(Label1.Text);
    using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
        {
            ICryptoTransform transform = tripleDes.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            Label1.Text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope so,It may help you but I'm confirming ,I'm too beginner to crypto as well as asp.net web-forms.

Answer (score 3):

> if this method is still "up to date"?

Yes, in general.

> I also never specify a salt but let it generate it (second parameter = null).

Yeah. Now hash like a hunderd thousand times and you are ok ;) No joke. I think minimum should be around - well, it should take a second to operate.

Now, here is the question you actually NEVER ASK EXCEP TIN YOUR TITLE. How do you verify?

NOT by decryption.

- Take password enterd by user.
- Take salt from your salted password (yes, store it)
- Take number of iterations from your salted password
- Salt input from user same number of times with same algorithm.
- Compare both hashes.

Finished.

Hash are NOT encryption. Envcryption means you can decrypt - Hashes are irreversible.

Comment: Thx for your comment! What do you mean with the following: "Yeah. Now hash like a hunderd thousand times and you are ok ;) No joke. I think minimum should be around - well, it should take a second to operate." ? I'm afraid that i didn't understand your joke xD.

Comment: It means that yes, I am serious when i tell you to hash it it a hundred thousand times, not one time. Yes, it is slow- that is the whole reason. Hash it, take output, hash it again in a loop until. How offten? SHould take about one second on a top end CPU.

Comment: Is it ok to let the method generate a saltsize? I personally  use a saltsize between 16 and 24.

Comment: What's the advantage to hash it more than once?

Comment: Dictionary attacks. Having precalculated hashes. How you do that then?